# Error when sending message to topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

hi please when i run kafka producer im displays this error
is what you need to delete the topics??

```
[2019-04-09 01:48:29,011] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer]
Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition
test2-0 due to
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This
server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request
metadata update now
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender) [2019-04-09
01:48:29,124] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2 with
key: null, value: 0 bytes with error:
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This
server is not the leader for that topic-partition. [2019-04-09
01:48:29,132] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received
invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test2-0 due to
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This
server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request
metadata update now
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```